# How to load data into Vue from an external file using Axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

how would you go about replacing the "image" data array in this example with an external JSON file? Basically I want to fetch/get this data externally with axios but something is not quite working yet in this example.  Any clue very much appreciated!

I also created a CodePen for this example working without the external reference if you prefer to look at it this way.  Thanks a lot!
https://codepen.io/FloydGekko/pen/eLoRBQ

This is the html, css and vue.js code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        [v-cloak] {
          display: none;
        }

        .imageBlock{
            width:100%;
            margin:10px;
        }
        div.polaroid {
            width:310px;
            height:440px;
            margin:10px;
            background-color: white;
            box-shadow: 6px 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 6px 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            border-radius: 18px
        }
        div.container {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="vue" v-cloak>
    <h2 align="center">
        Show
    <select v-model="currentKind" @change="onChange">
        <option v-for="kind, index in kinds" :value="kind" :key="`kind_${index}`">{{kind ? kind : 'kind...'}}</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="currentColor" @change="onChange">
        <option v-for="color, index in colors" :value="color" :key="`kind_${index}`">{{color ? color : 'color...'}}</option>
    </select>
        and
     <select v-model="currentShape" @change="onChange">
        <option v-for="shape, index in shapes" :value="shape" :key="`kind_${index}`">{{shape ? shape : 'shape...'}}</option>
    </select>
    </h2>

    <isotope
            id="root_isotope"
            ref="isotope"
            :options='options'
            :list="images"
            align="center">
        <div class="polaroid" align="center"
            v-for="(image, index) in images"
            class="imageBlock"
            :key="image.id">
            <a target="_blank"  :href="image.url"><img border="0" :src="image.pic" alt=""
            style="
                border-radius: 20px;
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 100%;">
            </a>
            <div class="container">
                <a target="_blank"  :href="image.url">
                <h3 align="center">{{image.title}}</h3>
                </a>


            <!--<h1>{{image.kind}}</h1>
            <h1>{{image.color}}</h1>
            <h1>{{image.shape}}</h1>
            <h1>{{image.id}}</h1>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </isotope>
    <h2 align="center">
        <button @click="reset">Show all</button>
    </h2>
</div>


<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/David-Desmaisons/Vue.Isotope/master/src/vue_isotope.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js'></script>

<script>
    let currentKind = null;
    let currentColor = null;
    let currentShape = null;
    let imageSearchString = null;


    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#vue',
        data() {
            return {
                currentKind:'',
                currentColor:'',
                currentShape:'',
                options: {
                    itemSelector: ".imageBlock",
                    getSortData: {
                      id: "id"
                    },
                    sortBy : "id",
                    getFilterData: {
                        Finder: function(itemElem) {
                            let kindSearch = currentKind ? itemElem.kind.indexOf(currentKind) !== -1 : true;
                            let colorSearch = currentColor ? itemElem.color.indexOf(currentColor) !== -1 : true;
                            let shapeSearch = currentShape ? itemElem.shape.indexOf(currentShape) !== -1 : true;
                            return kindSearch && colorSearch && shapeSearch
                        },
                    },
                },
                images: '',
            };
        },
        computed: {
            kinds(){
                let allTags = _.flatten(this.images.map(image => image.kind))
                return [''].concat(_.uniq(allTags))
            },
            colors(){
                let allTags = _.flatten(this.images.map(image => image.color))
                return [''].concat(_.uniq(allTags))
            },
            shapes(){
                let allTags = _.flatten(this.images.map(image => image.shape))
                return [''].concat(_.uniq(allTags))
            },
        },
        mounted(){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.onChange()
            }, 200)
        },

        created: function () {
            this.loadImages();
        },
        methods: {
            onChange: function() {
                currentColor = this.currentColor;
                currentShape = this.currentShape;
                currentKind = this.currentKind;

                this.$refs.isotope.filter('Finder');
                this.$refs.cpt.layout('packery');
            },
            reset(){
                currentColor = '';
                currentShape = '';
                currentKind = '';

                this.currentColor = '';
                this.currentShape = '';
                this.currentKind = '';
                this.onChange()
            },

            // THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE IN QUESTION I THINK
            loadImages: function () {
                var vm = this;
                axios.get('myimagedata.json')
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.images = response.data.images;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    vm.images = 'An Error occured.' + error;
                });
            }
        },
    });

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

And this is the external JSON file "myimagedata.json" I try to load with axios:

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "kind": ["A"],
            "color": ["Green", "Blue"],
            "shape": ["Square"],
            "pic": "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg",
            "url": "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg",
            "title": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "kind": ["B"],
            "color": ["Green", "Red"],
            "shape": ["Circle"],
            "pic": "https://www.kimballstock.com/pix/DOG/05/DOG-05-JE0078-01P.JPG",
            "url": "https://www.kimballstock.com/pix/DOG/05/DOG-05-JE0078-01P.JPG",
            "title": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can I see your `loadImages()` method you tried on `axios`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `axios` you should be able to do something like is below. You may need to write a `var self = this`. External libs rewrite `this` as their own so to access the `vue` `this` variable you will need to set a variable beforehand and use the new variable to set your data. In the future please show your code in question like your `loadImages()` and the error if any you were getting.

```
var self = this
axios.get('/myimagedata.json')
  .then(function (response) {
    self.images = response.data.images
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

With your `json` response here

```
{
"images": [{
        "id": 1,
        "kind": ["A"],
        "color": ["Green", "Blue"],
        "shape": ["Square"],
        "pic": "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg",
        "url": "http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_462/cy_245/cw_1349/ch_1349/w_720/APL/uploads/2015/06/caturday-shutterstock_149320799.jpg",
        "title": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "kind": ["B"],
        "color": ["Green", "Red"],
        "shape": ["Circle"],
        "pic": "https://www.kimballstock.com/pix/DOG/05/DOG-05-JE0078-01P.JPG",
        "url": "https://www.kimballstock.com/pix/DOG/05/DOG-05-JE0078-01P.JPG",
        "title": "B"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: I added your suggestions but it still won't load the data from the JSON quite yet.  I feel like it's very close but one tiny bit is missing.  I updated the initial question to the latest version I have with your suggestions implemented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. I noticed you this your images set to a string and not an empty array. Change `images: ''` to `images:[]`. Before loading the images your `computed` components can't load a map on an empty string.

Comment: Travor,  your are the man!  It's working!  Thanks a lot for your help and figuring that out.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: It's basically working in Firefox but unfortunately not in Chrome.  Also I'm getting a "Cross Origin Request Blocked" when I'm running it on the server so I'm trying to do this in vue.js only and created a new post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548952/how-to-load-data-into-vue-js-from-an-external-file-using-vue-only